# Eclipse can't find 32bit ncurses library

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, ncurses

I am running Ubuntu and need to use a 32 bit version of ncurses with my program. I downloaded ncurses-5.9 using wget from http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-5.9.tar.gz. I then entered:

```
gzip -dc < ncurses-5.9.tar.gz | tar -xf -
cd ncurses-5.9
```

At this point I followed all the instructions listed [here](http://cross-lfs.org/view/svn/sparc64/final-system/ncurses.html) (I have listed them below as well:

```
CC="gcc ${BUILD32}" CXX="g++ ${BUILD32}" \
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/lib \
--with-shared --without-debug --enable-widec \
--with-manpage-format=normal \
--with-default-terminfo-dir=/usr/share/terminfo

make
make install
mv -v /usr/bin/ncursesw5-config{,-32}
mv -v /lib/lib{panelw,menuw,formw,ncursesw,ncurses++w}.a /usr/lib

rm -v /lib/lib{ncursesw,menuw,panelw,formw}.so
ln -svf ../../lib/libncursesw.so.5 /usr/lib/libncursesw.so
ln -svf ../../lib/libmenuw.so.5 /usr/lib/libmenuw.so
ln -svf ../../lib/libpanelw.so.5 /usr/lib/libpanelw.so
ln -svf ../../lib/libformw.so.5 /usr/lib/libformw.so
```

All of these commands executed successfully. When I go to run my program however, I use the appropriate flag `-lncurses` yet I get back the error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses`

From the terminal I can see that `libncurses  libncurses++w.a  libncursesw.a  libncursesw.so` are  all in `/usr/lib` and `ncurses5-config  ncursesw5-config-32`
 are in `/usr/lib`.

Please advise as to what I should try to change, thanks much!